# Why was this VLQ flag on an off-topic answer rejected?

Tags: support, scope, low-quality-posts

Yesterday I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70829417/why-cant-i-declare-this-variable-within-while-loops/70829470#70829470) (now deleted by the author) as very low quality. My reasons were stated in a comment:

> The answer is off-topic since it's given in a different programming language. C doesn't have RAII so it's also irrelevant. Flagging this for deletion as very low quality as it can't be salvaged.

I double-checked that the question never had the C++ tag during all edits, in which case I would have done nothing. But it was always tagged C. Therefore the answer is completely off-topic and cannot be salvaged, since the two languages are very different here (and this answer confused the OP a lot).

Yet my flag was declined declined - "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

Does this text mean it was reviewed by an actual moderator or just by the VLQ review queue? In case of the latter I understand why it could get rejected, because you need a slight bit of domain knowledge about C and C++ to tell.

I'm curious to know why this flag was rejected.

Comment: Answering in the wrong language isn't a reason to flag as VLQ or NAA. It's a reason to Downvote, but not flag. VLQ is for answers that are *very low* quality; they consist of just a link or a statement that doesn't really address the question. The answer you've linked, though in the wrong language, does not look to be low quality in any way; it's not useful/helpful sure, but not low quality.

Comment: Also, as someone with 10K plus rep, you could have downvoted, and then immediately voted to delete (assuming you placed a downvoted before the upvote that was made on it was). Answers can be voted to be deleted as soon as they have a negative score (unlike questions, that need a -3 score).

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95581/the-limits-to-a-very-low-quality-answer/167641#167641; "You should not use it to describe the following, but should be using comments, close votes, downvotes and / or edits instead: [...] * Answers that are just wrong or even actively harmful"

Comment: @Larnu Why would we _not_ delete blatantly off-topic answers? That makes absolutely no sense. If I post a detailed answer about pony riding to that question, you don't think it's low quality? Of course it is, and it should be deleted.

Comment: I didn't say it shouldn't be deleted, @Lundin . I specifically stated you should have voted to delete it in my second comment. I said you should not *flag* it. Voting to Delete and flagging are *completely* different things.

Comment: The answer wasn't "off topic" either. It attempted to answer the OP's question; just the OP didn't answer in the right language. It's still an answer, and would result in the solution in that language. Saying that they answered about Pony rider is utter nonsense; they didn't.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah but what happens to it if I delete vote it? If it doesn't end up in review then that's broken and that single delete vote will just uselessly sit there. Because there are very few answers attracting enough attention to get enough random 10k+ people passing by and casting delete votes.

Comment: So it takes 30 minutes to be deleted instead of 5. So what? And the OP deleted the answer once you corrected them; they did the correct thing. I don't see the problem. Your downvote and comment would have solved the issue all along. There was *no need* for a moderator.

Comment: @Lundin The pool of possible users is even smaller, you need 20k to cast delete votes on answers. 10k allows such votes only on questions (with a certain delay).

Answer (score 7):

Summarising my comments:

Firstly, as I stated, flagging the answer was incorrect. The Very Low Quality (VLQ) flag is for answers that are **literally** very low quality; such as link only answers or answers that are a single statement that don't really answer the question:

> You should use Concatenation!

The answer you have linked isn't either of these. It is am attempt to answer the question just in the wrong language. That **does not** make it low quality, it makes the answer not useful/helpful and should (likely) be downvoted accordingly.

As a user with 20K+ reputation, you can also vote to delete an answer once it has a negative score. I note that the answer does have an upvote, so you may have been unable to do this, however, if you were the first voter you could have immediately voted to delete it if you downvoted it, as it would a score of -1.

As for your point about the answer being "off-topic", I completely disagree. The answer is very much an attempt to answer the question, and had the OP been using C++, maybe the answer was actually a really useful one. The answer was "on-topic" for the question, just in the wrong language. Unlike questions, that can have VTCs for being "off topic", answers don't have these. In fact, flags are specifically not for being used to denote the accuracy of an answer; that is what up/down votes are for.

---

All of this, however, is irrelevant as the problem solved itself; after you commented that the answer was in the wrong language the user admitted their mistake and deleted the answer. The problem solved itself.

---

TL;DR:

- The flag was incorrect; the answer was not "low quality"
- Instead you should have:

  1. Downvoted
  2. Voted to delete (if <= -1 score)
  3. Optionally comment to inform the user
  4. Moved on

You successfully did steps 1-3, it was just the flag that was incorrect.

Comment: I strongly disagree because the off-topic answer only served one purpose: to confuse the OP and everyone in the future who reads the question and then this answer. That is the _only_ thing it does. Review queues serve to remove low quality items from the site, they are not different boxes used for categorizing quality content. An odd-topic answer can by definition not be high quality.

Comment: Review Queues are not the determining the "correctness" of answers, @Lundin . Again, that is what up/down voting is for.

Comment: If there is no attempt to answer the question given the tags used, then it is not an answer by definition and it is low quality by definition. It needs to be deleted from the site, not polished, hugged and put on a pedestal for the sole purpose of confusing present and future readers.

Comment: It is an attempt to answer, @Lundin , and it isn't "low quality" per the definition of what low quality means... *"This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether."* The answer you linked was **not** meant to be *"an edit, a comment, another question"*.

Comment: No it is not, no more than my pony riding answer example, which would be similarly confusing and off-topic. This here just boils down to the meta "crap hugging" attitude. It shouldn't matter what label we put on crap - it simply needs to go. Rejecting a flag like this is like saying "I'm perfectly able to make the site better since I have the privileges for that, but no, I'm not deleting this crap because you filled in the wrong form and that's all that matters. Not the actual quality of content on the main site."

Comment: The only thing this question and that answer have to do with Pony Riding, @Lundin, is you keep bringing it up. But just you; no one else. You aren't going to accept my answer, I can see that, even with several of my comments being upvoted, none of yours being upvoted, and your question being strongly downvoted, so I'll leave the discussion now. I'll let the up/down votes speak.